# Compiling a Qt 5 application in Creator on Windows 8 that will run on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, qt, visual-c++

I have Windows 8.1, Qt 5.4 MSVC 2013 OpenGL installed, and MSVC 2013.

I want to compile my app so that it will run in Windows 7. I won't have access to a Windows 7 machine for a few days so I'd like to find a recipe to increase the chances that it will "just work". I'm familiar with how to distribute Qt applications (copying the DLLs into the application folder), but that was always a Windows 7 -> Windows 7 deployment.

Are there compiler target flags or something I have to set?  Do I need to use MSVC 2012?  I installed the Windows 7.1 SDK on my Windows 8.1 machine.

Thanks

Comment: It should just work if you supply the dlls right and both are the same archs (32 or 64 bits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should just work if you supply the dlls right and both are the same archs (32 or 64 bits).